# Scroll div to bottom when recharged

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I have a script that automatically reloads the contents of a div. The code works, however there is one thing I can not solve:

The first time I load the page the scrollbar goes to the bottom of the div (and that's fine), but when you update with the script (from the second onwards) the scrollbar stays up.

```js
<script>
  setInterval("my_function1();",5000);
  $("#interno_chat").scrollTop($("#interno_chat")[0].scrollHeight);
  function my_function1(){
    $('#interno_chat').load(window.location.href + ' #interno_chat');

  }
</script>
```

If i put the scrollTop-scrollHeight in my_function1 the code doesn't work even the first time.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  setInterval("my_function1();",5000);
  $("#interno_chat").scrollTop($("#interno_chat")[0].scrollHeight);
  function my_function1(){
    $('#interno_chat').load(window.location.href + ' #interno_chat', function() {
        $("#interno_chat").scrollTop($("#interno_chat")[0].scrollHeight);
    });        
  }
</script>
```

I suspect the issue is that you're not waiting for the content to be loaded.

See http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: I think the issue is that too... i've tried your code but nothing, the scrollbar stay on the top of the div. Do u know another way to fix this?